# What kinds of templates may be used with is_detected?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm interested in understanding what sorts of templates may be used as the first argument of `std::experimental::is_detected` and similar detection utilities.

Pasted below is an implementation of `is_detected` and an attempt at using it to detect whether a type `T` has a member function named `.foo()`. The general pattern it uses is to first define a type trait which returns the type of a member function `T::foo`, if it exists:

```
template<class T>
struct member_foo_result
{
  using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
};
```

Then, it defines a shorthand alias:

```
template<class T>
using member_foo_result_t = typename member_foo_result<T>::type;
```

The problem is that the shorthand alias seems to be incompatible with `is_detected`.

Here's the full program, with compiler output:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// implementation of is_detected
template<class...> 
using void_t = void; 

struct nonesuch 
{ 
  nonesuch() = delete; 
  ~nonesuch() = delete; 
  nonesuch(const nonesuch&) = delete; 
  void operator=(const nonesuch&) = delete; 
}; 


template<class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
         template<class...> class Op, class... Args> 
struct detector 
{ 
  using value_t = std::false_type; 
  using type = Default; 
}; 


template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args> 
struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> 
{ 
  using value_t = std::true_type; 
  using type = Op<Args...>; 
}; 
template<template<class...> class Op, class... Args> 
using is_detected = typename detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t; 



// returns the result type of T::foo()
template<class T>
struct member_foo_result
{
  using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
};

// shorthand alias for member_foo_result<T>::type
template<class T>
using member_foo_result_t = typename member_foo_result<T>::type;


// detects whether or not the member function T::foo() exists
template<class T>
struct has_foo_member : is_detected<member_foo_result_t, T> {};


struct doesnt_have_foo_member {};


int main()
{
  std::cout << "result: " << has_foo_member<doesnt_have_foo_member>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I expect this program to print "result: 0" at runtime. However, it does not compile correctly:

```
$ clang -std=c++11 test_is_detected.cpp 
test_is_detected.cpp:41:43: error: no member named 'foo' in 'doesnt_have_foo_member'
  using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
test_is_detected.cpp:45:1: note: in instantiation of template class 'member_foo_result<doesnt_have_foo_member>' requested here
using member_foo_result_t = typename member_foo_result<T>::type;
^
test_is_detected.cpp:27:33: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'member_foo_result_t' requested here
struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> 
                                ^
test_is_detected.cpp:33:1: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'detector<type-parameter-0-0, void, Op, type-parameter-0-2...>' [with Default = nonesuch, Op =
      member_foo_result_t, Args = <doesnt_have_foo_member>]
using is_detected = typename detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t; 
^
test_is_detected.cpp:50:25: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'is_detected' requested here
struct has_foo_member : is_detected<member_foo_result_t, T> {};
                        ^
test_is_detected.cpp:58:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'has_foo_member<doesnt_have_foo_member>' requested here
  std::cout << "result: " << has_foo_member<doesnt_have_foo_member>::value << std::endl;
                             ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I misusing `is_detected`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_detected` is meant to be used with alias templates that cause an error in the immediate context (i.e., SFINAE-friendly) when instantiated with "wrong" arguments.

That means that the substitution failure to be detected needs to occur in the alias template itself, rather than some class template it instantiates:

```
template<class T>
using member_foo_result_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
```